# My Facebook News Feed is blank and it won’t let me log out

Tags: facebook

On my laptop, I can not log out of Facebook. My home page is blank; when I go to click on anything in the site toolbar—i.e. "home" or Messages—nothing happens.

Comment: Is your whole browser frozen? If so, have you tried using something like Task Manager (on Windows) to force-close it? Or is it just Facebook? If it's just Facebook, you should try clearing your browser's cache and deleting any cookies pertaining to Facebook. (By definition, deleting the cookies should solve your logout issue, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a Facebook issue. It is your browser problem. Try to login with other browsers. Clear the cache in current browser.